# CSS .wf-inactive

Tags: html, css, google-webfonts

Will adding the following code to my CSS work in providing an alternative font whilst the webfont from Google is inactive? All I have done is add the following link to my HTML:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display|Shrikhand" rel="stylesheet">
```

I've added this to the CSS:

```
.wf-inactive body {

font-family: serif;
font-size: 1em;
line-height: 1.4em;
letter-spacing: 0;
word-spacing: 0.035em;
margin-top: 0.65em;
margin-bottom: 0.55em;

/* To match body, p, section, etc's active content */

}
```

Is there anymore to it than this?

Comment: Of course there is - someone's gotta remove that class again when the font has loaded. And just embedding the font style sheet does of course not accomplish this. The provide ready-made code for this at Google Fonts, IIRC, so go have a look at that.

Comment: I haven't yet no, I'm still going through this online course. I just wondered if in order for '.wf-inactive' to work it needs a script or something? Or does the browser recognise it on its own? I will find out with testing soon but I'm still relatively new to this. Thanks.

Comment: That class has to be added to the `html` element (because that is the only element above `body`, so only then will this selector match) to begin with - so that the fallback font is applied. And then it has to be removed, by some script logic that detects that the web font has finished loading.

Comment: But the fallback font will work using '.wf-inactive' on my body element as the code stands now?

Comment: html, not body. As long as it does not get overwritten by a more specific rule ... yes.

Comment: Great, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using a font stack, which is specifically designed so that if one font fails, your browser will fall to the next one in line.

```
font-family: 'Playfair Display', Arial, sans-serif;
```

What this tells your browser is to prioritize Playfair, and if that doesn't work, switch to Arial. If your user doesn't have Arial, it'll switch to the default san-serif on their computer.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense.

Comment: Sidra, you are right but during loading of PlayFair is could show Blank.
reference : https://slides.com/frontendmasters/responsivetypography#/77